# NSMutableArray insertObject don't work

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsmutablearray

i try to insert data in my NSMutableArray :

this is a part of my code:

```
 newArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

 fileArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: file];
            [newArray insertObject:dict atIndex:[fileArray count] ];
```

it's crash with this error:

```
[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: index 11 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

thanks for reading

Comment: You code isn't complete. What is newArray?

Comment: ok just edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
newArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
fileArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: file];
[newArray addObject:dict];
```

Comment: need to have a index with function insertObject

Comment: Your right, my mistake, I meant to use `[newArray addObject:dict];`   Hope this helps anyway.

Answer (score 3):

1. NSMutalbeArray: insertObject:atIndex: method, the index value must not be greater than the count of elements in the array.
2. NSMutalbeArray: initWithCapacity: method,  even though specify a size when create the array, the specified size is regarded as a “hint”; the actual size of the array is still 0.
3. The only method you can do to insertObject:atIndex, is to ensure to initialize all the elements before the index value.

   ```
   for(int i = 0; i< index; i++)
   {
       [array addObject:[NSNull null]];
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert an object at an index that is greater then the array count.

This is because you are inserting the object into newArray, which has a count of 0 when you initialize it.

If you are really wanting to add the object to newArray, use index 0.

Comment: I think you are confused about what is happening. you are resetting newArray and fileArray every time this code runs.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as far as I know, when you call:

```
 NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 20]
```

It will create and return an NSMutableArray object with **enough memory to initially hold a given number of objects. This is not a number of objects itself.**

So, (*probably this isn't a good way*), you can fill your array with some null-objects like this:

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    [array addObject:[NSNull null]];
}
```

And now you can use **replaceObectAtIndex:WithObject:** method for your purposes. Because I guess this is what you want (**insertObject:AtIndex:** — means that you are going to insert an object at some index, but the rest part of the array (after that index) will "move", and there will be array.count+1 items now).

```
[array replaceObjectAtIndex:someIndex withObject:someObject];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't add an object at a specific index if that index doesn't exist, and the way you're creating your array creates one with a length of 0.

You can either predefine the size of the array like this:

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:20];
[newArray insertObject:object atIndex:index];
```

Or you can just insert objects from the beginning and let the array grow from 0, like this:

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[newArray addObject:object];
```

Which will put it at index 0 if it's the first time you add an object, at index 1 the next time, etc.

Comment: i really need insertObject  not addOject. i try with initWithCapacity but don't work

Comment: Why do you need insertObject? You are putting this item into a new array. Unless, you really don't want to put this in newArray but fileArray.

Comment: if i addObject i will lost what i have before in my file becaue i use  [newArray writeToFile:file atomically:YES];

Comment: so i want to use insertObject in my file to keep my datas.

Comment: It will crash when we insert object at Index 'i' where 'i' is greater than Array count. Suppose Array is empty initially. [newArray insertObject:object atIndex:2]; will crash out of the App

Comment: @rakeshNS That is true. Did I indicate otherwise? Why the downvote?